# Programatically show hide button in drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I've got a sign up page with an anchor button for signing up, but when a user is logged in the form is hidden but the content should still be visable just hiding the join now button, im trying to display the button based on the vistor id, so basically i only want to show it to anonymous users not authenticated

Comment: Question should be moved to http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <?php
global $user;
  if ($user->uid)

return;

else
{
print '<div id="landing-left-button">
    <a class="button" href="#join-anchor">Click Here To Join</a></div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Also `global` variables are bad and you should feel bad.

Comment: Matt, are you familiar with Drupal? global $user is the only way to get user object. You can take a look here http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/user/7 Globals are also used while checking if user is logged in or not.http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_is_logged_in/7

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to do it like this:

```
if (! user_is_logged_in()) {
  print <<<EOT
    <div id="landing-left-button">
      <a class="button" href="#join-anchor">Click Here To Join</a>
    </div>
EOT;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input out of interest why would you regard this better? because of the use of the "user_is_logged_in" api hook rather than basing it on a variable?

Both work but would like to know better methods

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what is your use-case... But  in this case, you will have to use globals. That's how we usually check/get user's data.

```
<?php
 if (user_is_logged_in()){
  // do something for logged in users.
 }
 else{
  //do something for anoynmous users. 
 }
?>
```

[user_is_logged_in()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_is_logged_in/7) function returns TRUE if the user is logged in (duh!).